# where do we configure cucumber test database configuration location in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am new to Rails Project,

i was struck in some issue regarding writing unit test cases using cucumber.
while executing the test cases the data should be stored in test data base,but in my case it is flushing the development database and then again inserting the data into the development database,resulting the wrong data at wrong place.

please,tell me where the configuration lies for executing the cucumber unit test cases.

Comment: could you post you database.yml file?

Comment: This is my database.yml file:
        # SQLite version 3.x
#   gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
#
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"`. 
Add

```
cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

To your database.yml file.